# How to remove line breaks in between image tags

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how to remove line breaks between and after image tags, but leave any others (using jQuery). For example:

```
<p>
   some text
   <br>
   more text
</p>
<br>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
<br>
<br>
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="image">
<br>
<img src="image3.jpg" alt="image">
<br>
```

Would become:

```
<p>
   some text
   <br>
   more text
</p>
<br>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="image">
<img src="image3.jpg" alt="image">
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest, for the posted code:

```js
// select all <img> elements:
$('img')
  // select all sibling elements of
  // the <img> elements that match the
  // supplied ('br') selector:
  .siblings('br')
  // remove those found siblings:
  .remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  some text
  <br>more text
</p>
<br>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
<br>
<br>
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="image">
<br>
<img src="image3.jpg" alt="image">
<br>
```

For slightly more complex cases (as well as this one), though, the following may be preferred:

```js
// select all <img> elements:
$('img')
  // get all subsequent siblings until an element
  // is found which matches the supplied selector
  // (':not(br)'), in this case the selector matches
  // any element that is not a <br> element:
  .nextUntil(':not(br)')
  // we remove those elements that are found
  // which must be <br> elements, given the
  // above selector:
  .remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
some text
<br>more text
<br>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
<br>
<br>
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="image">
<br>
<img src="image3.jpg" alt="image">
<br>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:not()`, CSS Negation pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation).
- jQuery:

  - [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img + br').remove(); try this
```

Answer (score 0):

It remove all `<br>` tag between images.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("img").nextUntil('img').remove();

});

<p>
  some text
  <br>
  more text
</p>
<br>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
<br>
<br>
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="image">
<br>
<img src="image3.jpg" alt="image">
```